# Capture screenshot of current web site in Universal Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-10, win-universal-app

Here is how I can capture screen shot of current webpage, but sometimes it is capturing only visible area of webview (what user actually see).
But I'm not sure what was wrong.
I think `var heightString = await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" })` was finish too late - but program should wait in `if (!int.TryParse(heightString, out height))` to complete... Am I wrong?

```
private async Task CaptureWebView()
{
    int width;
    int height;
    var originalWidth = WebView.Width;
    var originalHeight = WebView.Height;
    // ask the content its width
    var widthString = await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollWidth.toString()" });
    // ask the content its height
    var heightString = await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });
    if (!int.TryParse(widthString, out width))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get page width");
    }
    if (!int.TryParse(heightString, out height))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get page height");
    }

    // resize the webview to the content
    WebView.Width = width;
    WebView.Height = height;

    await DoCapture("captured.png");

    WebView.Width = originalWidth;
    WebView.Height = originalHeight;

    Painter.Width = width;
    Painter.Height = height;

    var i = await LoadCaptured("captured.png");
    Painter.Fill = i;
}
```

Test repository [on Github](https://github.com/Sebosek/WebInking)

Comment: Is the failure consistent? for certain sites, for example or does behaviour vary for the same site? a repro would help, not just a description and part of the code.

Comment: Actually I'm testing it only on one site. Anyway I added link to github repo to original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end problem itself was in `WebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync()` method. I used it to capture full web screen shot, but it didn't work very well. But then I found `WebViewBrush` and realized that is the right way.

So here is final code snippet or [GitHub](https://github.com/Sebosek/Sebastian.WebInk)

```
private async Task CaptureWebView()
{
    int width;
    int height;
    var originalWidth = WebView.ActualWidth;
    var originalHeight = WebView.ActualHeight;

    var widthString = await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollWidth.toString()" });
    var heightString = await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });

    if (!int.TryParse(widthString, out width))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get page width");
    }
    if (!int.TryParse(heightString, out height))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to get page height");
    }

    // resize the webview to the content
    WebView.Width = width;
    WebView.Height = height;

    var brush = new WebViewBrush();
    brush.SetSource(WebView);

    Painter.Width = width;
    Painter.Height = height;
    Painter.Fill = brush;
}
```

Comment: The link to github is broken